# Composition of Formal Power Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Is there a known closed form for the composition of the following power series:
$$f(x) = \exp(x) = \sum_k \frac{x^k}{k!}$$
$$g(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_n x^n$$

I'd like a closed form power series for $g(f(x)) = \frac{1}{1-\exp (x)}$. I've been trying to use the [di Bruno formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula#Formal_power_series_version) from Wikipedia but I find it very confusing, I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: $g(f(x))$ is not continuous or differentiable at $x = 0$.  So, if you wanted to find a power series representation you would need to center it somewhere away from 0, and not use the well known series above.  Or you could say something like $\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty e^{nx}$ or $-\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty e^{-nx}$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you mean a closed form for the coefficients.  There is no simple closed form known (or at least that I know of), but these are essentially the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) defined by $$ \frac{x}{e^x - 1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$ Your sum is then $$\frac{1}{1-e^{x}} = \frac{-1}{x} \frac{x}{e^x-1} = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n \frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}.$$

Note that there is an $x^{-1}$ term here, so this not actually a power series, but a [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series).

Comment: Great explanation, thank you

Answer (score 4):

**hint**

$$g(f(x))=\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\frac{1-e^x}{x}}=$$
$$\frac{1}{x}g(h(x))$$ with
$$h(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}-1$$